# How can I make an AJAX call for the simple JQuery button click event

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I have been doing this which keeps on refresh the page for every new request ,

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $('#wordsubmit').on('click', function () {
        var wordSearchValue = $("#mainword_search").val();
        if (/\s/.test(wordSearchValue)) {
            wordSearchValue = wordSearchValue.replace(/ /g, '-');
        }
        else {
            sessionStorage.setItem("data", wordSearchValue);
            var pathParameter = 'word-' + wordSearchValue;
            window.location.href = "/search/" + pathParameter + '-examples';
        }
    });
});
```

In my flask app I have the view method as:

```
@app.route('/search/<word>-examples', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def word_details(word):
    query=word_search_query(word)
    data=db['wordsdata'].aggregate(query) // get a cursor
    return render_template('worddetails.html',data=data)
```

May I know how can I make an AJAX call on the same for which I read it loads the contents without actually reloading the page,

I have tried as:

```
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $("#wordsubmit").on('click', function () {
        var wordSearchValue = $("#mainword_search").val();
        if (/\s/.test(wordSearchValue)) {
            wordSearchValue = wordSearchValue.replace(/ /g, '-');
        }
        if (wordSearchValue == '') {
            //pass
        }
        var pathParameter = 'word-' + wordSearchValue;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/search/" + pathParameter + '-examples', success: function (result) {

               //what to do here ??
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am exactly looking on how to make an AJAX call for the above one which I used a simple JQuery

Any help or guiding links are much appreciated , TIA

Answer (score 1):

Refer this to ajax call. and fetch in div. what data you want.
ajax call from URL and fetch data.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.ajax({url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", success: function(result){
    console.log(result[0]['title']);
      $("#div1").html(result[0]['title']);
    }});
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>
```